# rails generate controller Comments not creating the files it should create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Am following ruby on rails documentation and am hooked here, it dosen't seem to create expected files, i need some help please.

```
C:\Sites\blog>rails generate controller Comments
```

i ran the code above but got this instead.

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load': C:/Sites/blog/config/routes.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:55:in `block in load_paths'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:55:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:55:in `load_paths'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:18:in `reload!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `block in updater'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:81:in `execute'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:42:in `updater'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:31:in `execute_if_updated'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:128:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Sites/blog/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:329:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:329:in `require_environment!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:16:in `require_application_and_environment!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/generate/generate_command.rb:19:in `perform'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

 - List item
```

Please help me, and is documentation the best place for learning rails

Comment: If you have analyzed the above error, in the first line itself, it clearly says its syntax error.. `C:/Sites/blog/config/routes.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)`

Answer (score 0):

Your `routes.rb` has an error in it somewhere. Backup your existing `routes.rb` file and then change it to,

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

end
```

Then run your generate command. Afterwards, add the previous contents back into `routes.rb`